# jQuery fadeIn() jumps to top of page

Tags: jquery

I've got custom jQuery tabs (not UI) that work great. However, since the tabs use `fadeIn()`, when you click the different tabs, it will jump to the top of the page.

I've looked at these two solutions (below) and it seems that setting the **height** does solve the jumping issue. However, I do not want to set the height statically. I've tried to dynamically set the height but I cannot make it work for some reason. I've also tried to load the content (`load()`) but cannot get it to work either.

[jQuery fade making page jump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574508/jquery-fade-making-page-jump)

[JQuery fadeIn/fadeOut image on click jumps while loading new image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832723/jquery-fadein-fadeout-image-on-click-jumps-while-loading-new-image)

My **HTML** code is this:

```
<ul class="port-tabs">
<li><a href="#tab1">Web Design &amp; Dev</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">Graphic Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">Photography</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="port-slides slides-list tab-container">
<div id="tab1" class="port-subpages tab-content">
    <ul class="portfolio">
  <li>
<div id="port-window">
    <span class="window"></span>
    <span class="gradient"></span>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/port-image1.jpg" alt="" title="" width="223" height="225" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-112" /></a>
</div>
  </li>
  <li>
<div id="port-window">
    <span class="window"></span>
    <span class="gradient"></span>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/port-image2.jpg" alt="" title="" width="223" height="225" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-112" /></a>
</div>
  </li>
  <li>
<div id="port-window">
    <span class="window"></span>
    <span class="gradient"></span>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/port-image3.jpg" alt="" title="" width="223" height="225" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-112" /></a>
</div>
  </li>

  <li>
<div id="port-window">
    <span class="window"></span>
    <span class="gradient"></span>
    <a href="#"><span class="port-just-text">TEXT PLACEHOLDER 1</span></a>
</div>
  </li>
  <li>
<div id="port-window">
    <span class="window"></span>
    <span class="gradient"></span>
    <a href="#"><span class="port-just-text">TEXT PLACEHOLDER 2</a>
</div>
  </li>
  <li>
<div id="port-window">
    <span class="window"></span>
    <span class="gradient"></span>
    <a href="#"><span class="port-just-text">TEXT PLACEHOLDER 3</a>
</div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<p class="clearBoth"></p> <!-- Temporary fix: remove when live -->
<div id="tab3" class="port-subpages tab-content">
    <p>Tab Content 3</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery** code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab-content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.port-tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab-content:first").show(); //Show first tab content


    //On Click Event
    $("ul.port-tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.port-tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab-content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        //activeHeight = $(activeTab).height();
        //alert(activeHeight);
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can someone please help eliminate the jumping to the top upon clicking a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because your anchor tags.
Try adding these lines

```
  $("ul.port-tabs li").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: how about removing <a> tags and use CSS to create those mouseover effects?

Comment: Because `var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");` is a key part of these tabs and I'm trying to not rewrite the tabs portion. I think I have an acceptable workaround for this. I'm testing it out and then I'll post the answer.